# How to combine two ngrx action reducers in to single one in angular?

Tags: angular

The following is the reducer code for a single action.

```
on(apiContentActions.deleteApiContentsSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      success: true,
    };
  }),
  on(apiContentActions.deleteApiContentSuccess, (state, action) =>
    adapter.updateOne(
      {
        id: action.apiContent.contentId,
        changes: { ...action.apiContent, text: 'deleted' },
      },
      state,
    )
  ),
```

Instead of writing separately, how can I combine them in to a single snippet?

something like this:

```
on(apiContentActions.deleteApiContentsSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return adapter.updateOne(
        {
          id: action.apiContent.itemId,
          changes: { ...action.apiContent, text: 'deleted' },
        },
        state,
      )
    &&
    {
      ...state,
      success: true,
    };
  }),
```

Nothing else. Just to combine the reducer functions in to a single body>=